# Encoding of Umlauts while importing into R tables

Tags: r, character-encoding, sqldf

I need to join two tables on the colum `name`. They come from different excel spreadsheets which I didn't create. I imported both sheets into `R` tables using the function `read.xls` from the `gdata` package.

Sometimes the names contains umlauts and other accents. They appear identical within the excel sheets but when I import them into R they are not the same. Hence my join doesn't join. I join using the `sqldf` function.

As an example : I see `Lück` in the two spreadsheets. In table1 of R this appears as `L\374ck` whereas in table2 it appears as `L\303\274ck`.

How can I best solve this problem? Is there a way to force an encoding when data is imported? Or should one try to force the comparison of strings in a different way?

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you know what OS the data were produced under? (OS = Operating System)

Comment: OS is OSX on a mac (snow leopard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you stated you are not geting a TRUE on agstudy's code, I'm assuming you're using a Mac or a Linux Machine.

Try instead

```
x1=  "L\374ck"
x2 = "L\303\274ck"
iconv(x1,"latin1","UTF-8")
[1] "Lück"
identical(iconv(x1,"latin1","UTF-8"),x2)
[1] TRUE
```

Tested this on a Linux CentOS 7. I believe it should work on Macs too. If not look into

```
?iconv
```

for more details on encoding.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I didn't realise that information was relevant. Well deduced!

Answer (score 1):

It is an encoding problem.
For example :

```
 x1=  "L\374ck"
 x2 = "L\303\274ck"
 identical(iconv(x2,"UTF-8","UTF-8"),x1)
 [1] "TRUE"
```

So you can try this for example before applying merge :

```
 df2name <- iconv(df2$name,'UTF-8','UTF-8')
```

Comment: When I run your example I get `[1] FALSE`

Comment: @Geoff Seban answer should help.